# How to continue on keypress OR do something else by entering 1 in batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a simple text-based game and am trying to design fighting mechanics. Right now, once you enter a fight you have to either type "1" to attack or "2" to enter the fightmenu. I want to change it so that you can just press space to do a regular attack, but still be able to type "1" to open the fightmenu. Here is the code so far if you're interested:

```
:fighting
cls
set /a yourhit=%random% %%dmg%
set /a theirhit=%random% %%theirdmg%
set /a armor = %armor% - %theirhit%
if %theirhit% gtr %armor% set /a armor = 0 & set /a hp = %hp% - %theirhit%
if %yourhit% geq %theirhp% goto winner
if %theirhit% gtr %hp% goto loser
set /a theirhp = %theirhp% - %yourhit%
echo.
call :fightheadsup
echo  - You hit them for %yourhit%!
echo.
echo  - They hit you for %theirhit%!
echo.
echo  1.Continue Attacking
echo  2.Return to Fight Menu
echo.
set /p input12=Enter:
if %input12% equ 1 goto fighting
if %input12% equ 2 goto fightmenu
goto fightmenu
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose compared values in a pair of `"`double quotes`"` as follows (get used that *always* as a value could be empty or could contain a blank space character, in particular a value *entered by a user*):

```
if "%input12%" equ " " goto fighting
if "%input12%" equ "1" goto fightmenu
```

Another approach: set a default value in advance (self-explained in code):

```
echo.
echo  1. Continue Attacking ^(default choice, hitting ^<Enter^> suffices^)
echo  2. Return to Fight Menu
echo.
set "input12=1"
set /p "input12=Your entry [default=%input12%]:"
if "%input12%" equ "1" goto fighting
rem superabundant: if "%input12%" equ "2" goto fightmenu
goto fightmenu
```

Note proper [escaping `<`, `>`, `(` and `)` characters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) in `echo 1. ...` command

Answer (score 0):

In this type of applications is preferable to use `choice` command instead of `set /P`, because CHOICE get one key and continue without need to press Enter key:

```
choice /C 12 /N /M "Enter: "
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto fightmenu
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto fighting
```

The disadvantage of CHOICE command is that it can not read a space key. However, in important advantage of CHOICE over SET /P is that in CHOICE command you *never* will get a wrong input, so you may directly use CHOICE answer this way:

```
choice /C 12 /N /M "Enter: "
goto option-%errorlevel%
. . .


:option-1  fighting
. . .


:option-2  fightmenu
. . .
```